# Is it possible to code Swift on windows using JetBrains AppCode?

Tags: swift, windows, ide, appcode

Is it possible to write proper Swift-code using the AppCode IDE from JetBrains? I'm looking for an option to build a native iOS-app without buying a macbook or iMac. I've been looking and searching for a while now and coudn't find any solution without buying the additional hardware. With the AppCode IDE it seems like I don't have to.

If you have any ideas or experience let me know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically no you can't. 
if you are planning to develop ios app you have to buy macbook  or install hackintosh  or rent a mac on the cloud or virtualise || virtualbox